# Find person address by name API for Canada

Tags: api

looking for an API for Canada like WhitePages/YellowPages?

WhitePages API only does the USA, YellowPages API only does business listings in Canada.

Anyone ever had luck in this area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the Google Maps API for that?

Googling for "Canada geocoding" also pulls up some interesting results.

Comment: My mistake, I meant for finding addresses of people.  I edited the title

Comment: http://developer.whitepages.com/forum/read/16339 points to http://pro.whitepages.com/ as a paid alternative.

Comment: free is better, but this is a solution.  Thanks